# C# : 2 combobox column Data Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am working on a `C#` project. I have a `datagridview` with a `combobox` column include, so far so good :). You can find the code below. But I would like to add two choices when I click it (see image below).
How can I do? Have you a track for me?

PS: I am French, excuse me for my English level ^^ child.

[image: Schema]

Code :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); 
cmb.HeaderText = "Opérateur";           
cmb.Name = "cmb";
cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
cmb.Items.Add("Florence");
cmb.Items.Add("Julie");
cmb.Items.Add("Christophe");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please elaborate what you actually want.

Comment: After an item selected, clear items on combobox and put new 2 values in it ?

Comment: Thank's for your responses, @Berkay i've try your tip but I can't select an item Visual Studio doesn't accept :  if(cmb.Selecteditems.ToString=""){

          }